# Redux testing- asyncthunk not updating redux state

Tags: reactjs, redux, jestjs, react-testing-library, redux-toolkit

I am learning React and Redux. I have been trying to do integration testing on a react component, that dispatches an action to fetch data from external API. I have used MSW to mock the fetch request. I have also used a Reusable Test Render Function as in [redux documentation](https://redux.js.org/usage/writing-tests). when I custom render the component, I expect the mock data from API to be updated in the state and rendered in another component. So far, I see that the store is not getting updated with data from API. I have checked the MSW api mock. It is returning the value I have provided. Can someone please point me in the right direction.

my test file

```js
import { screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import renderWithProvider from '../utils/test-util';
import { rest } from 'msw';
import { setupServer } from 'msw/node';
import MissionsPage from '../components/missions/MissionsPage';

const missions = [
  {
    id: 'testmission1',
    name: 'test1',
    descriptions: 'test mission',
    isReserved: false,
    wiki: '',
  },
];

export const handlers = [
  rest.get('https://api.spacexdata.com/v3/missions', (req, res, ctx) => {
    return res(ctx.json(missions));
  }),
];

const server = setupServer(...handlers);

beforeAll(() => server.listen());
afterEach(() => server.resetHandlers());
afterAll(() => server.close());

test('testing Mission page UI', async () => {
  const { store } = renderWithProvider(<MissionsPage />);
  console.log(store.getState().missions);
  const text = screen.getByText('/test mission/i');
  expect(await text.toBeInTheDocument());
});
```

Component I am trying to render

```js
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import MissionsTable from './MissionsTable';
import { fetchMissions } from '../../redux/missions/missionSlice';

const MissionsPage = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const status = useSelector((state) => state.missions.toFetch);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (status) {
      dispatch(fetchMissions());
    }
  }, [status, dispatch]);
  return (
    <MissionsTable />
  );
};

export default MissionsPage;
```

my reusable test render function

```js
import React from 'react';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import missionSliceReducer from '../redux/missions/missionSlice';

function renderWithProviders(
  ui,
  {
    preloadedState = {},
    store = configureStore({
      reducer: { missions: missionSliceReducer },
      preloadedState,
    }),
    ...renderOptions
  } = {}
) {
  function Wrapper({ children }) {
    return <Provider store={store}>{children}</Provider>;
  }

  // Return an object with the store and all of RTL's query functions
  return { store, ...render(ui, { wrapper: Wrapper, ...renderOptions }) };
}

export default renderWithProviders;
```

slice where I have defined the Async thunk.

```js
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const initialState = { missions: [], toFetch: 'true' };

export const fetchMissions = createAsyncThunk('missions/fetchMissions', async () => {
  const response = await fetch('https://api.spacexdata.com/v3/missions');
  return response.json();
});

const missionSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'missions',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    bookMission: (state, { payload }) => {
      const newArr = state.missions.map((misObj) => {
        if (misObj.id === payload) {
          if (misObj.isReserved === true) {
            return { ...misObj, isReserved: false };
          }
          return { ...misObj, isReserved: true };
        }
        return ({ ...misObj });
      });
      const newState = { ...state };
      return { ...newState, missions: newArr };
    },
  },
  extraReducers(builder) {
    builder.addCase(fetchMissions.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      const newState = { ...state };
      const missionList = [];
      action.payload.forEach((misObj) => {
        missionList.push({
          id: misObj.mission_id,
          name: misObj.mission_name,
          description: misObj.description,
          wiki: misObj.wikipedia,
          isReserved: false,
        });
      });
      newState.missions = missionList;
      newState.toFetch = false;
      return newState;
    });
  },
});

export const { bookMission } = missionSlice.actions;
export default missionSlice.reducer;
```

this is the error I am getting.

```js
 console.log
    { missions: [], toFetch: 'true' }

      at Object.<anonymous> (src/__tests__/missionUI.test.js:31:11)

 FAIL  src/__tests__/missionUI.test.js
  ✕ testing Mission page UI (85 ms)

  ● testing Mission page UI

    TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element with the text: /test mission/i. This could be because the text is broken up by multiple elements. In this case, you can provide a function for your text matcher to make your matcher more flexible.

    Ignored nodes: comments, script, style
    <body>
      <div>
        <div>
          <div
            class="table-responsive-sm"
          >
            <table
              class="missionTable table table-striped table-bordered table-hover"
            >
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>
                    Mission
                  </th>
                  <th>
                    Description
                  </th>
                  <th>
                    Status
                  </th>
                  <th>
                     
                  </th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody />
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>

      30 |   const { store } = renderWithProvider(<MissionsPage />);
      31 |   console.log(store.getState().missions);
    > 32 |   const text = screen.getByText('/test mission/i');
         |                       ^
      33 |   expect(await text.toBeInTheDocument());
      34 | });
      35 |
```

Comment: I don't know the solution but I think I know the problem.  You're looking at the page on the first render.  It's not waiting for the API call to be completed.

Comment: @LindaPaiste Hi Linda, I used waitFor() from RTL and made assertions inside that function. Works as expected. Thank you for taking your time

Comment: if you were able to get it working then you should answer your own question with what you changed.  This will help others who have the same problem in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I used awaitFor() to make assertions, and data is available in the DOM.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).